# Impossible to get part of URL with react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I always get the same part of the URL in react?

example:
http://localhost:3000/supplier/924511e8-9056-4c1e-9976-625bf042924e

I only want "supplier", but this can be anything else. So it's possible for it to be:
http://localhost:3000/product/924511e8-9056-4c1e-9976-625bf042924e
Then I want "product"

But it can also be just http://localhost:3000/supplier/ also in this case I only want the supplier. And this can be anything.

How do I do this? If I've already tried it with  `pathname.slice(0, pathname.indexOf("/")` but this doesn't seem to work.

So I only want the string after the http://localhost:3000/`want this`/ no matter if there is anything after it or not.

Comment: You should not display the UUID of the table to the client

Comment: Oke, then How do I fix this if the URL would be:

http://localhost:3000/supplier/supplier-name
or
http://localhost:3000/product/product-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the split method as below:

```
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/supplier/'
const want_this = url.split('/')[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use useParams from react router dom

```
      import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
      
      
          function Child() {
            // We can use the `useParams` hook here to access
            // the dynamic pieces of the URL.
            let { id } = useParams();

            return (
              <div>
                <h3>ID: {id}</h3>
              </div>
            );
          }
```